# How do you center navigation bar text in xcode storyboard?

Tags: swift, storyboard

I have looked this up a few times and I can't seem to find an answer. I am very new to programming IOS applications, so there may be a much easier way to do this, I was just following a tutorial.

[current view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NMWZQ.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select the navigation bar in of the navigation controller. Open attribute inspector from the right panel. Then deselect **Prefers Large Titles**.
[image]

[image]

Comment: That solved my problem appreciate the help.